# Regex Extract on Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to find an expression that can be used extract a string after a specific number of characters.

E.g

```
FR_EN_BR_Student_Exact

FR_EN_NB_Student_Exact
```

I would want a pattern that can take all characters past the second underscore ( not including the underscore.
Would appreciate any ideas!

I understand basic regex but am having trouble with this specific query.

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty  of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ".+_.+_(.+_.+_.+)")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for that. Works just fine. why dies the regex expression have to be out into an ARRAYFORMULA?

Comment: because of range A1:A. if you instead use A1 you dont need arrayformula

Comment: Great, makes sense